# How to reduce the wait time when an element is not found in selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This question is some thing different.
In my program i have more than 9 expected assertions.So, i have to reduce the wait time time if an element is not found.

```
for i in range(len(10)):
    try:
        i.click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("XXX").send_keys("XXXX")
    except Exception,e:
        print "this is an expected assertion so as to continue the program further iteration"
```

In the above program due to the Unable to find element assertion it taking a lot of time..
How can i reduce the wait time...

Comment: I don't want to set the default time... I want to decrease the default time

Comment: Then use the command to set the default time, to a lower value. That's all you'd need to do.

Comment: Why do you want to have such an effect? If you can find them there are mostly two reasons: you are looking for the wrong element or you can't find the element because you haven't retrieved them so far.

Comment: @Jon I need to iterate the steps which is mandatory and i know there is no element in those iterations except in one case

Answer (score 0):

add `import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui` to your header.

the `WebDriverWait` object will wait until it find what you want :

```
try:
    timeout = 10
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    wait.until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_name("XXX").send_keys("XXXX")
    )
except TimeoutException:
    # timeout
```

edit :

`WebDriver` has a default of 60 sec internal timeout (it's the ruby doc, but it should be the same for python) :

> Internally, WebDriver uses HTTP to communicate with a lot of the
>   drivers (the JsonWireProtocol). By default, Net::HTTP from Ruby's
>   standard library is used, which has a default timeout of 60 seconds.
>   If you call Driver#get on a page that takes more than 60 seconds to
>   load, you'll see a TimeoutError raised from Net::HTTP.

Try to reset the timeout like that :

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(0)
driver.set_script_timeout(0)
```

doc : [set_page_load_timeout](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=timeout#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout), [set_script_timeout](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=timeout#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_script_timeout)

Comment: There is no element to find in every iteration so i want to decrease  the default time...